Is there a way to clip content with ellipsis in SwiftUI
How can I clip any TextView that was not 100% visible in its parent container? Here's a playground that show the problem
    import SwiftUI
    import PlaygroundSupport

    struct TruncatedTripView: View {
  
      let purpose = "Experience cultural diversity, visit iconic sites like Big Ben                                           and Stonehenge, and savor British cuisine"

      let activity = "Taking the Jacobite Steam Train in Scotland, better known as                                                 the “Hogwarts Express, through breathtaking highland landscapes."
      
      let goal = "Explore historic landmarks, immerse in British culture, and enjoy                                                                       the scenic countryside."

      let fact = "The UK is home to the oldest underground railway system, the                                London Underground, which began operations in 1863"
   
      var body: some View {

         VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12.0) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Trip Purpose")
                  .font(.headline)
                Text(purpose)
             }
                     
              VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                  Text("Destination Facts")
                     .font(.headline)
                  Text(fact)
              }
          
             VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                  Text("Most Excited Activity")
                    .font(.headline)
                  Text(activity)
              }

              VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                  Text("Goal")
                    .font(.headline)
                  Text(goal)
              }
         }
         .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
         .frame(width: 360, height: 330, alignment: .top)
         .clipped()
     }
 }


// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(TruncatedTripView())


Here's the actual result:

The expected result should have ellipses appended to the clipped text. In this case the goal text.

If I understand correctly:

all subviews should be visible within the frame that you set
as much of the text should be shown as possible
there should be no overflow, so if the text does not fit fully, it should be truncated with ellipses
if truncation is necessary, the subviews at the end should truncate first.

To control the truncation, try applying .layoutPriority to the subviews. The documentation says:

Raising a view’s layout priority encourages the higher priority view to shrink later when the group is shrunk and stretch sooner when the group is stretched.

So the first view should be given the highest priority, the last view the lowest priority. Then:

Remove the modifier .fixedSize, otherwise none of the views will truncate.
The .clipped modifier is redundant and can be removed too.

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12.0) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Trip Purpose")
                .font(.headline)
            Text(purpose)
        }
        .layoutPriority(4) //  added

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Destination Facts")
                .font(.headline)
            Text(fact)
        }
        .layoutPriority(3) //  added

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Most Exciting Activity")
                .font(.headline)
            Text(activity)
        }
        .layoutPriority(2) //  added

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Goal")
                .font(.headline)
            Text(goal)
        }
        .layoutPriority(1) //  added
    }
    // .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) //  removed
    .frame(width: 360, height: 330, alignment: .top)
    .border(.red)
    // .clipped() //  unnecessary
}

In your original example, the strings had a lot of spaces in them. I assume that the multiple spaces should be reduced to a single space. Then, when a frame of 360x330 is applied, the views for "Most Exciting Activity" and "Goal" both need to truncate. This is because, there isn't space for a full line of the "Goal" text when the other views are all shown in full (the height is insufficient for one line, as can be seen from your screenshot of the clipped views):


I wouldn't use fixedSize or a set frame width here- that's the main problem of text being cropped unintentionally in your screenshot. I'd let the contents overflow as needed. Then if you want to truncate text, you could do something like .lineLimit(2) instead of .lineLimit(nil) below and the view would truncate after two lines of text.
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

private struct NewspaperText: Identifiable {
    let title: String
    let body = "Hello This is a very long text. Hello This is a very long text. Hello This is a very long text. Hello This is a very long text. Hello This is a very long text. Hello This is a very long text. Hello This is a very long text. Hello This is a very long text. Hello This is a very long text. Hello This is a very long text. Hello This is a very long text."
    var id: String { title }
}

struct TruncatedView: View {
    private let items = [
        NewspaperText(title: "Trip Purpose"),
        NewspaperText(title: "Destination Facts"),
        NewspaperText(title: "Most Excited Activity"),
        NewspaperText(title: "Goal")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                textView(item)
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }

    private func textView(_ item: NewspaperText) -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
            Text(item.title)
                .font(.headline)
            Text(item.body)
                .lineLimit(nil)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(TruncatedView())



Your implementation is close. But I need the truncated text to end with ellipses. if you replace the scrollview with a VStack had a width of 360 points to it, you will see that the "Most Excited Activity" Text gets clipped. I want any clipped/truncated text to end with ellipsis i.e ...
